# Calculating the infinite approximation to infinite amount of given function as an argument with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the approximation to infinite amount of given function as an argument with lambda function, for example i'm trying to calculate the approximation of amount:

[image]

for now I have written this code:

```
def infinite_sum(form):
    i=1
    sum_of_sigma=0
    while i < 100000:
        sum_of_sigma+=form(i)
        i+=1
    return sum_of_sigma
```

and I'm trying to use this function like this:

```
print(infinite_sum(lambda i : 1/(3^i)))
```

but unfortunately I'm getting this error when I try to run the code:

[image]

someone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: `3^3 = 0` <- you are dividing by zero. You can try running with the `**` operator instead

Comment: thank you very much! it was my problem!